# uploaded image path is getting double

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

http://localhost/name/Projects/work/CodeIgniter223Grocery151Smarty3127_Pack/uploads/http://site name//uploads/Card_Designs_vqd1q1o8.jpg

```
         public function uploadEdesignimage()
           {
              $data=$this->data; // for geting paths


                $id=$this->session->userdata('id');
                $email=$this->session->userdata('email');
                 $data['getuser']=$this->ecard_model->getUser($id);
                 $name=$data['getuser']->name;

                $createdon= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $temptype= $_POST['temptype'];
                $path = $_FILES['uplaodimg']['name'];


                $imgext=strtolower(strrchr($path,'.'));
                 $imgname="Card_Designs_".$this-     >generateRandomString().$imgext;
                if($path!='')
                 {

                    $im= $this->config->item('base_url').'/uploads'.'/'.$imgname;

                    $x=$this->do_upload($imgname);
                     $img=array('image'=>$im,'name'=>$name,'email'=>$email,'designtype'=>$temptype,'createdon'=>$createdon);
                    $this->ecard_model->insertUploadedImages($img);



                    }

                     }    this is my controller function
```

//ajax is used for uploading image

```
           $("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {

          if ($('#uplaodimg').val()!='' & $('#temptype').val()!='')
           {
              e.preventDefault();
               var f=$('#uplaodimg')[0].files[0].size/1024;

                  if (f > 1024)
                    {
                        $("#msgsizeupload").removeAttr('style');
                     }
                    else
                     {
                       $("#sucessimage").empty();
                       $("#Msgupdbtn").attr('disabled','disabled');
                       $('#divMsgupd').show();

                        $.ajax({
                         url: "{{$site}}/ecarddesigns/uploadEdesignimage", // Url to which the request is send

                           type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method           
                            data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
                             contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
                              cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached   
                                 processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
                                 success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
                                    {
                                       //alert(data);  die();
                                        $('#divMsgupd').hide();
                                                                             $("#msgafterupload").removeAttr('style');
                                      setTimeout(function()
                                          {
                                         window.location="{{$site}}/ecarddesigns/loadEdesign";
                                         }, 5000);
                                              }
                                          });
                                        }    
                                        }
                                       else
                                          { 
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                  if ($('#uplaodimg').val()=='')
                                    {
                                $('#imageupload_err').html('Please select the image before upload')
                                        }
                                            else
                                               {
                                        $('#imageupload_err').html('Please select the design type')
                                           }
                                         }

                                         }));
```

used for fetching the image.modal is used ,ajax is used for it.

Comment: how to customize groceycrud.php file? in database the image path is correct but in the admin panel in groceycrud the path get doubled .so the image can not be appear in the site.

Comment: Edit your question in proper way, including code/snippet.

Comment: need more details and code

Comment: <img src="http://localhost/ASoft/Projects/Ecarddesign/CodeIgniter223Grocery151Smarty3127_Pack/uploads/http://ecarddesigns.com//uploads/Card_Designs_vqd1q1o8.jpg" height="50px">

Comment: in admin panel i got this as my image path

Comment: show the code that you are using to fetch the image.

Comment: CodeIgniter2.2.3Grocery1.5.1Smarty3.1.2.7_Pack is using

Comment: @JeenaThomas Please update your original question instead of posting lengthy comment chains. That will be much more conducive to getting a helpful answer.

Comment: <img src="http://localhost/ASoft/Projects/Ecarddesign/CodeIgniter223Grocery151Smarty3127_Pack/uploads/http://ecarddesigns.com//uploads/Card_Designs_vqd1q1o8.jpg" height="50px">       Why link is doubling here?